# Using Geometry Nodes, how do I make modular fence components perfectly follow

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I'm trying to make a generic geonodes wall generator.  I'm going to be working almost exclusively in grids, and would like to be able to just draw out my walls including 90 turns.
[image]

The above is using my node set-up on 4 curves and manually placing them together.

If I try and use 1 curve I get this:

[image]

I tried to avoid using the curve tangent, because of course that will not make a square, even
when the handles are set to vector.

Instead, I converted the curve to a mesh, and then tried to use the vectors between the new vertices to align the fence.

[image]

It *mostly* works.

[image]

As you can see in my second image, the curve is a square. The generated vertex positions look right.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this geo node setup, maybe this will help you. I used the edges normals for the vector socket in the align vector to euler to get the planks to be aligned correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great, but it still doesn't work for Bezier curves.  For some reason Blender appears to ignore the request to align with generated edges and instead averages out values.

Comment: try to resample the curve to evaluated